# Failed "Close Votes" audit, closed Q. as "non-reproducible" (common error)

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed this question that was presented as an audit in "Close Votes" review queue.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/25346314

I voted to to close it as "non-reproducible", as I've seen *many* other reviewers do, *only* because the OP indicated in the comments that their problem was resolved. I now realize in and of itself, that is insufficient justification to close a question. By looking at the text of the non-reproducible option more carefully (included below), I see the category offers qualification for *when* to choose it, but reviewers are commonly missing the 'subtlety' and apply it haphazardly.

I assume the underlying sense people voting to close those questions have is that questions resolved in comments don't need to stick around, maybe because they don't think they are 'archival quality', whatever that means (e.g. subjective). Perhaps many questions are seen as 'trivial' very user-specific problems that would not be valuable to a wider audience, but who knows? Sometimes I stumble on some idiosyncratic noobish question whose answer shed light on a problem I was having. So, even though the qualification for choosing that response is clear, it is easily and often gotten wrong.

Interestingly, the next review question that came up for me is a similar situation: (1) Question asked, (2) Someone's comment helps, (3) OP replies problem is solved. And, yet again, a reviewer opted to close it as `non-reproducible`, even though it's clearly a `duplicate`.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/25342424

Thus, it is an ***extremely common*** way reviewers are handling questions like that in the review queue, wherein the question-asker *merely indicates in comments their problem is resolved*, and *wham!* it's voted to close as non-reproducible. I'll avoid doing so in a knee-jerk way, but it seems to be a commonly confused and abused category resulting in many potentially valuable questions getting closed inappropriately.

Fortunately one audit saved me from my own ignorance, but unfortunately audits that catch that oversight may be far and few between...

[image]

Comment: Why would a question being answered make it no longer reproducible? (wrt your first link) If anything it might be a duplicate of something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218964/often-big-numbers-become-negative

Comment: @NickA Yeah, good point. I guess I just got that figured wrong in the first place and didn't occur to me until I got it wrong.  Plus re-reading the specific text of the non-reproducible case it qualifies it as saying it's for solutions that wouldn't be helpful for other users. So, live and learn. I know how to deal with it now.

Comment: Not reproducible is to be used when if you copy and paste the code in your environment then run it, it doesn't exhibit the error described, thus aiming at a problem on OP machine and not with the code, thus not answerable without checking OP machine.

Comment: Yeah, that reason is for problems that could *never* be reproduced, rather than have been fixed/answered so there's no longer a problem

Comment: BTW, my upvote for asking openly and not ranting the audit was bad :D

Comment: @clearlight As for your second link, the OP was clearly helped by the link to another post, so I'd say it's more a duplicate of that than no-repro