# Should I flag robo-reviewers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension, review-abuse

After this question ([Adding a threshold for closing/reopening duplicate question to limit "robo-reviewers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393400/8620333)) where nothing will be done, I am wondering if I can at least flag "robo-reviewers"?

I am really tired about trivial duplicates reopened by two blind votes from users with no activity in the related tag. The two votes usually come after an automatic reopen vote done by the OP where no edit is made to the question or the trivial edit "*my question isn't a duplicate ..*"

Here are some screenshots of a user involved in the reopening of some [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) questions that should be kept closed (I manage to re-close them again with the help of another Gold badge)

> [image]

> [image]

Based on the above, it's hard for me to believe that we can review a question within a few seconds. 4 questions in only 30 seconds considering the time for the page to reload, to read the question (to check the duplicate if it's about duplicate closure) and to click the button. This is not the only pattern, I found a lot for the same user and many other users.

Is such behavior worth a flag?

Most important question: Are the reopen/close queue safe for *spammers*? Can they click as fast as possible with no way to stop them (audits, ban, etc.)?

To be clear, I am not accusing a random user based on timestamps. That user (and others) made wrong decisions reviewing some questions. To this I add the fact that they did it for tags where they aren't active and later I consider their reviewing speed. Based on that I concluded that they are a spam reviewer.

Comment: If they're making incorrect reviews as a result, _absolutely_ you should flag them

Comment: ..but it seems they voted to "Leave Closed" :)

Comment: @Scratte I picked a random pattern to highlight the speed factor because I think we need more than 30s to review 4 questions

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. I was just a little confused for a moment there. There is also a chat room for [bad reviews](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews), though I am not sure if you can directly post users in there.

Comment: Note that it strongly depends on the question how long a review takes. On some, the decision to hit leave closed can take mere seconds. Deciding to reopen, however, should always take some time.

Comment: @ErikA true, but I discovered such repeated pattern after I discovered many bad decisions so it was another argument to consider this as spam. This also raises the issue of having such queue free from any control (unlike others where we have audits)

Comment: @Scratte that room seems to deal only with editing

Comment: @TemaniAfif It was used to post only bad Triage reviews, but I have posted both Late Answers and First Posts in there. Now the starboard says ["I think we can relax the only-Triage rule now since the campaign is over. Feel free to report any egregious review that needs attention"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49710848#49710848) by Samuel Liew, so I think any review can be posted there.

Comment: @Scratte the bad review I discover are related to question I myself close with gold badge. I can easily fix them by calling another gold badge, this isn't an issue BUT my concern is how to prevent/stop this because it's difficult to identify since there is no control over that queue and if I am able to identify few cases because I was involved in the closure, there is for sure more than that with no way to identify them

Comment: There are audits for both the [Close Vote queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393936) and the [Reopen queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393495), so I assume they cannot continue clicking mindlessly. But as Nick pointed out, flagging as a good option when you notice such. Finding a new innovative way to handle it needs a proper Answer though.

Comment: @Scratte good to know there is audits for this but I am wondering if there is audits with duplicate close reason.

Comment: to be honest, the people do what they can, and try to help reviewing the cr... other people wrote. Sometimes the cr.. is as bad as it comes and you can click fast forward, a typo corrected for example, hightlight of text and such sh... so without knowing what exactly was to be review your images and highlighted reviews doesn't tell us nothing..just my 2 cents

Comment: @nbk I am not talking about reviewing edits. This is out of the scope of the question. I am talking about openinig/closing question where you need to at least read and understand the question and sometimes also read the duplicate. The images I shared show reviews related to "closed" question

Comment: as i stated, that also for closure votes and reopen. Most closure votes come quite fast, people mostly are missing vital details or cocus, so that canbe automated by an ki, who has to learn all programming languges there are, and what is necessary to a question. Most close votes are from someone who has at least a bronze batch or a high rep that they can often see at a gance that the close vote is ok, that is really no rocket sciece, sometimes rarely the decison was not the best, but every user can edit his post and get into the reopen review and try there there luck, as it is small,you get it

Comment: @nbk as I also stated in my question, I noticed that such user are reviewing question with tags where they have 0 activity. If you have at least 10 Rep in the related tag then I may consider this as a different opinion but someone reopening a trivial duplicate where I see no activity in the related tag is suspicious for me.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Also consider that the questions might have all been really bad. It might have been open ended questions that the user spammed.

Comment: @10Rep your comment is rendered moot by the last paragraph of the OP.

Comment: @Gimby Sorry, what does "moot" mean?

Comment: @10Rep Technically, it means "debatable", but a lot of people use it to mean "null/void" or "refuted".

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes...if they're making mistakes.

Sometimes I can tell a question is bad the moment I look at it. If the question body is just a screenshot of an app's UI with "it doesn't work, why could this be? anyone know?" under it, there's a good chance I'll cast my vote within 10 seconds of opening the review.  Questions this bad are fairly common in the tag I curate most.

But if, like here, someone's going fast and either missing things or just blatantly guessing, you should definitely flag that (by putting a custom flag linking to examples on a relevant post).  It's worth doing this for people reviewing incorrectly even if they're doing so more slowly, too.  But the combination of fast + wrong is worth calling out in the flag.

Comment: I see the theme isn't actually the speed, but the accuracy, so "slow and wrong" is just as bad as "fast and wrong" :)